# Cadastrar hora exata no bd

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, time

Bom dia, sou um programador iniciante, e estou desenvolvendo um app web de vendas, onde preciso inserir no bd a hora exata da venda, mas não estou conseguindo.

> Código em javascript que gera a hora em tempo real:

```
    <script language="javascript">

        function showTimer() {

            var time=new Date();

            var hour=time.getHours();

            var minute=time.getMinutes();

            var second=time.getSeconds();

            if(hour<10) hour ="0"+hour;

            if(minute<10) minute="0"+minute;

            if(second<10) second="0"+second;

            var st=hour+":"+minute+":"+second;

            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=st;
        } function initTimer() {

            setInterval(showTimer,1000);
        }
    </script>
```

> Formulário:

```
<div id=timer align="center"></div>

<input type="hidden" name="timer">
```

> E a conexão com o Banco:

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "narguile");

$number = count($_POST["input_quantidade_venda"]);

$soma_venda = $_POST['soma_venda'];

$data = $_POST['data'];

$hora = $_POST['timer'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO vendas(preco_venda, data, hora) VALUES";
$sql .= "('$soma_venda', '$data', '$hora')";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

$id_venda = mysqli_insert_id($connect);

if($number > 0) {

    for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++) {

        if(trim($_POST["input_quantidade_venda"][$i] != '')) {

            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO venda_produto(quantidade, id_venda) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["input_quantidade_venda"][$i])."', '$id_venda')";
            mysqli_query($connect, $sql2);
        }  
    }

    echo "Venda cadastrada!";  
}  

else {

    echo "Não rolou";  
}
?>
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, eu agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `CURDATE()` e `CURTIME()`

```
// ...
$sql = "INSERT INTO vendas(preco_venda, data, hora) VALUES";
$sql .= "('$soma_venda', CURDATE(), CURTIME())";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
// ...
```

### Na definição da tabela `vendas` um `DEFAULT`

```
CREATE TABLE vendas
(
    // ...
    data DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

### `ALTER TABLE` com `DEFAULT`

```
ALTER TABLE vendas MODIFY COLUMN data DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

---

Em qualquer uma dessas hipóteses escusaria de ter código "extra" apenas para gravar a data e hora atuais na base de dados.

Comment: haha, vlw, João, eu estou iniciando, e ainda não manjo nada...